# Частота слов в тексте

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Здравствуйте!

Задача такая - подсчитать частоту слов длиннее 3-х символов в двух .txt файлах общим размером ~3мб. Набросал код и, собственно вопрос, что в нем можно улучшить. Код:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
  Action<Dictionary<string, int>, string> countWordsFrequency =
      (words, text) =>
        {
          const string pattern = @"[А-яЁёA-z]{4,}";

          MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

          foreach (Match match in matches)
          {
            if(words.ContainsKey(match.Value))
              words[match.Value]++;
            else
              words.Add(match.Value, 1);
          }
        };

  var result = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

  for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
  {
    string patch = string.Format(@"C:\U\book{0}.txt", i);

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(patch, FileMode.Open))
    {
      var reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default);
      string line = reader.ReadToEnd();

      countWordsFrequency(result, line);
    }
  }

  // сортировка здесь очень не нравится. Как можно обойтись без нее?
  foreach (var pair in result.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).Take(5))
    Console.WriteLine(pair);
}
```

ps.И еще такой вопрос - код с паттерном `(?>[А-яЁёA-z]{4,})` (то есть, с использованием атомарной группировки) в среднем выполняется чуть медленнее представленного (9408949 тактов против 9118863). Так вот, почему так происходит? Ведь атомарная группировка напротив должна облегчить труд парсера.

pps. парсер регулярок ругается при использовании ревнивого (сверхжадного) квантификатора. Я правильно понял, что .net по умолчанию ищет самое длинное соответствие?

Comment: Простите великодушно, а зачем вам `Action<>`, если вроде бы достаточно просто ещё одной функции в там же классе?

Comment: @VladD, Action<> как бы намекает, что эта функция только для этой конкретной задачи. Да и не в нем суть, в принципе

Comment: @Veikedo: Ах, это типа локальной функции? Понял. Тогда по делу: почему бы не разбить файл на слова по пробелам/переводам строки, и очистить от знаков препинания? 

    File.ReadLines(patch)
        .SelectMany(string.Split)
        .Select(s => s.Trim('.', ',', ':', ';')).
        .GroupBy(s => s)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);

Comment: Вероятно потому, отрабатывает медленнее, потому что движок регексов понимает, что при работе с таким регулярным выражением не нужно сохранять точки возврата, а используя атомарную группировку Вы заставляете его делать какие-то лишние действия.

Comment: Я понимаю, что суть не в том, но в ASCII между `A` и `z` есть 6 "не букв".

По поводу сортировки. Если надо именно 5 (или около того) самых часто встречающихся, то можно придумать что-то типа вставки в список. Тогда время выполнения этой части будет порядка N (где N это число разных слов).

А вообще, мне не нравится подход, когда файлы целиком считываются в память (особенно когда ее освобождением нельзя управлять).

Comment: Если гнаться за скоростью, то еще можно скомпилировать регулярное выражение.

Также не рекомендуется использовать InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, вместо него лучше взять OrdinalIgnoreCase.